# Showing Error: "[object with reference: partner_id - partner.id] " for function return

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I create a function for button(Send By SMS)  wizard action in Odoo10. In this function when i return value in the function following error shows on the screen. I also Define button action in sale order inherit file.

The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:
- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set

[object with reference: partner_id - partner.id]

So, What i return instead of code?

My Python and XML Code is Here:

```
**Pythode Code:**

    import urllib2
    import cookielib
    from getpass import getpass
    import sys
    import os
    from stat import *

    class way2smsBase(models.Model):
        _name = "way.base"
        _rec_name = "user_name"

        user_name = fields.Char(string="UserName", required=True)
        password = fields.Char(string="Password", required=True)

    class SaleMail(models.TransientModel):
        _name = "sale.mail.wizard"
        _description = "Sale Mail Wizard"

        message = fields.Text(String="Message", size=140)
        number = fields.Text(string="Receiver Number", required=True, size=12)
        user_acc = fields.Many2one("way.base", 'ACC', required=True)
        date_time = fields.Datetime(string="Date & Time", readonly=True)

        def sendSms(self):
            url = 'http://sunarctechnologies.com'
            data = 'username=' + self.user_acc.user_name + '&password=' + self.user_acc.password + '&Submit=Sign+in'
            cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
            opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
            opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent',
                                  'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120')]
            try:
                usock = opener.open(url, data)
            except IOError:
                raise Warning(_("Error pls Check account or mobile number"))
            jession_id = str(cj).split('~')[1].split(' ')[0]
            send_sms_url = 'http://site24.way2sms.com/smstoss.action?'
            send_sms_data = 'ssaction=ss&Token=' + jession_id + '&mobile=' + self.number + '&message=' + self.message + '&msgLen=136'
            opener.addheaders = [('Referer', 'http://site25.way2sms.com/sendSMS?Token=' + jession_id)]
            try:
                sms_sent_page = opener.open(send_sms_url, send_sms_data)
            except IOError:
                raise Warning(_("Error pls Check account or mobile number"))
            self.date_time = str(datetime.now())
            raise Warning(_("Message Sent"))

        @api.one
        @api.constrains('number')
        def validatePhonenumber(self):
            for phone in self:
                if re.match("[0-9]", phone.number) == None:
                    raise Warning("Mobile number is not valid one, Please specify valid number")
                    return False
                return True

        @api.multi
        def action_mail_add(self):
            rec = self._context.get('active_ids', [])
            print "REC"
            if rec:
                line_values = {'message': self.message,
                               'number': self.number,
                               #'user_acc': self.user_acc,
                               #'date_time': self.date_time,
                               }
                print "Values:", line_values
                #return line_values
                return self.env['sale.order'].create(line_values)


**XML Code:**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="view_sale_mail_wizard" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">SaleMail</field>
            <field name="model">sale.mail.wizard</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Sales mail">
                    <sheet>
                        <!--<separator string="SMS"/> -->
                        <group string="Way2SMS" style="width: 40%%" col="2" colspan="2">
                            <field name="user_acc"/>
                            <field name="number"/>
                            <field name="message"/>
                            <field name="date_time"/>
                        </group>
                    </sheet>
                    <footer>
                        <button name="action_mail_add" type="object" String="Ok"
                                class="oe_highlight" icon="fa-commenting-o" confirm="Are you sure want to send sms"
                                attrs="{'invisible':[('date_time','!=',False)]}"
                                help="this button will send an sms "/>
                        <button string="Cancel" class="btn-default" special="cancel"/>
                    </footer>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record id="action_view_sale_mail_wizard" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">SaleMail</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">sale.mail.wizard</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
            <field name="target">new</field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>

**XML Code in Sales Order Inherit File:**

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="custom_order_form">
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
            <field name="name">Sale Order Pet Form</field>
            <field name="model">sale.order</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <data>
                    <xpath expr="//button[@name='action_quotation_send']" position="after">
                        <button name="%(action_view_sale_mail_wizard)d" string="Send by SMS" type="action" class="btn-primary"/>
                    </xpath>
                </data>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the code here

```
    @api.multi
    def action_mail_add(self):
        rec = self._context.get('active_ids', [])
        print "REC"
        if rec:
            line_values = {'message': self.message,
                           'number': self.number,
                           #'user_acc': self.user_acc,
                           #'date_time': self.date_time,
                           }
            print "Values:", line_values
            #return line_values
            return self.env['sale.order'].create(line_values)
```

**partner_id** is  a mandatory field. and also with the partner id there are lot of fields related.

Comment: Yes Partner_id is mandatory field and i done this with:

line_values = {'message': self.message,
                           'number': self.number, 
      'partner_id': 1,
                           #'user_acc': self.user_acc,
                           #'date_time': self.date_time,
                           }
            print "Values:", line_values
            #return line_values
            return self.env['sale.order'].create(line_values)

Answer (score 1):

Yes Partner_id is mandatory field and I done this with set partner_id = '1':

```
line_values = {'message': self.message,
                           'number': self.number, 
               'partner_id': 1,
                           #'user_acc': self.user_acc,
                           #'date_time': self.date_time,
                           }
            print "Values:", line_values
            #return line_values
            return self.env['sale.order'].create(line_values)
```